# Replacing missing values in a data frame with the row mean

Tags: r

I have a data frame with entries running from 0 to 5 where 0 means a missing entry. I want to repalce the missing entries with the mean of each row. The mean should be calculated only on the not missing values. How do I do that?

For example, the row:

```
[1] 1 2 4 0 3
```

Will become:

```
[1] 1.0 2.0 4.0 2.5 3.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
set.seed(42)
m <- matrix(sample(0:5,15,TRUE),ncol=5)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    5    4    4    4    5
# [2,]    5    3    0    2    1
# [3,]    1    3    3    4    2

t(apply(m,1,function(x) {x[x==0] <- mean(x[x!=0]); x}))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    5    4 4.00    4    5
# [2,]    5    3 2.75    2    1
# [3,]    1    3 3.00    4    2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for your example above:

```
vec[vec == 0] = mean(vec[vec != 0])
```

you can wrap this in a function and use `apply` to do it for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

While perhaps not as streamlined as using `apply`, this may be more efficient for large data sets

```
set.seed(7)
m <- matrix(sample(0:5,15,TRUE),ncol=5)
m

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    5    0    2    2    4
# [2,]    2    1    5    1    0
# [3,]    0    4    0    1    2
```

Identify undesireable values and replace with `NA`

```
bad <- m==0
m[bad] <- NA
```

Calculate means of rows ignoring `NA` and replace bad values with correct row mean

```
m[bad] <- rowMeans(m, na.rm=T)[row(bad)[bad]]
m

#          [,1] [,2]     [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,] 5.000000 3.25 2.000000    2 4.00
# [2,] 2.000000 1.00 5.000000    1 2.25
# [3,] 2.333333 4.00 2.333333    1 2.00
```