# Replacing Zero and Infinite Values for the Value of the First column

Tags: r, matrix, replace

n the matrix example below (Stocks Return) :

```
       IBOV        PETR4        VALE5       ITUB4        BBDC4        PETR3
[1,] -0.03981646 -0.027412907 -0.051282051 -0.05208333 -0.047300526 -0.059805285
[2,] -0.03000415 -0.030534351 -0.046332046 -0.03943116 -0.030090271 -0.010355030
[3,] -0.02241318 -0.026650515  0.000000000 -0.04912517 -0.077559462  0.005231689
[4,] -0.05584830 -0.072184194 -0.066126856 -0.04317056 -0.066704036  0.000000000
[5,]  0.01196833 -0.004694836  0.036127168 -0.00591716 -0.006006006  Inf
[6,]  0.02039587  0.039083558  0.009762901  0.01488095  0.024169184  0.011783189
```

I would like to replace the 0 (Zeros) and Inf values for the values of the same row in the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample matrix

```
set.seed(15)
stocks<-matrix(rnorm(3*5), nrow=3)
stocks[cbind(c(2,3,1),c(4,4,2))] <- 0
stocks[2,2] <- Inf
stocks

#            [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
# [1,]  0.2588229  0.000000  0.0227882 -1.075001  0.1655543
# [2,]  1.8311207       Inf  1.0907732  0.000000 -1.2427850
# [3,] -0.3396186 -1.255386 -0.1321224  0.000000  1.45928777
```

Now we can find the bad values, and then replace them with the values in the first column of the same row by using matrix indexing and the `row()` function to find the correct row.

```
bad <- stocks==0 | is.infinite(stocks)
stocks[bad] <- stocks[row(bad)[bad], 1]
stocks

#            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
# [1,]  0.2588229  0.2588229  0.0227882 -1.0750013  0.1655543
# [2,]  1.8311207  1.8311207  1.0907732  1.8311207 -1.2427850
# [3,] -0.3396186 -1.2553858 -0.1321224 -0.3396186  1.4592877
```

Comment: Great ! My first col is the index daily return, so what i want is when a stock return is = 0 or Inf, that this value get replaced for the return of the index on this day, so i changed to code to :
stocks[bad] <- stocks[row(bad)[bad],1]
I was trying to adapt the answer that i found here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710147/replacing-missing-values-in-a-data-frame-with-the-row-mean) for this situation.
Do you think this is possible ?

Comment: @RiskTech Sorry about that, I flipped my answer and example around as well. Replacing with a mean is a different question and it's not a good idea to ask new questions in comments. I don't really have room to answer here, but i'd probably replace bad values with `NA` and then use `rowm<-rowMeans(na.rm=T)` and then use `<-rowm[row(bad)[bad]]`

Comment: thanks for your attention and feedback. Won´t use comments to do this anymore.

Comment: @RiskTech I've added my strategy as an answer to that question. But the accepted answers should work just fine as well.